# EventListener doesn't trigger second time when passing a named function but triggers normally when passing the complete function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple function for etch-a-sketch and came across this problem. I attached eventListener to the color and erase buttons like this:

```
eraseBtn.addEventListener("click", function erase(){
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", function eraser(event){
        let elem = event.target.closest('div');
        if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });
});

coloringBtn.addEventListener("click", function color(){
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", function coloring(event) {
        let elem = event.target.closest('div');
        if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
        let randColor1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        let randColor2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        let randColor3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randColor1}, ${randColor2}, ${randColor3})`;
    });
});
```

This functions as it is supposed to i.e, when I click color you can draw color and by clicking the erase you can erase the color you drew. However, this variant works on the first click and doesn't work afterwards:

```
function erase(){
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", eraser);
}
function eraser(event){
        let elem = event.target.closest('div');
        if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    };
eraseBtn.addEventListener("click", erase);

function color(){
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", coloring);
};
function coloring(event) {
        let elem = event.target.closest('div');
        if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
        let randColor1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        let randColor2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        let randColor3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randColor1}, ${randColor2}, ${randColor3})`;
    };
coloringBtn.addEventListener("click", color);
```

Here is the working demo for the second case:
[Codepen Link because SO snippet is not working for me.](https://codepen.io/alimustafa-poder/pen/bGoOyLm)

Why is the second one not working as expected and the first one is working fine?

Comment: Adding event listeners from inside other event listeners is *almost always* a mistake.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd avoid adding events inside other events, just because it gets messy. Setting a variable with e.g. `var mode = 'erase'` that controls the result of mouse moves would be significantly more reliable.

Comment: @Pointy So we shouldn't pass an event into another event altogether?

Comment: The function is called **add** event listener. Every "click" will add **another** mouseover listener.

Comment: @Pointy I understand now clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is lacking here is the ability to [remove event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Presently both erasing and coloring can happen at once on mouseover. Additionally, some booleans to track state will help guarantee the outcome.

```js
let erasingEnabled = false;
let coloringEnabled = false;

eraseBtn.addEventListener("click", function erase(){
    erasingEnabled = !erasingEnabled;

    if (erasingEnabled) {
        coloringEnabled = false;
        document.removeEventListener("mouseover", coloring);
        document.addEventListener("mouseover", eraser);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mouseover", eraser);
        document.addEventListener("mouseover", coloring);
    }
});

coloringBtn.addEventListener("click", function color(){
    coloringEnabled = !coloringEnabled;

    if (coloringEnabled) {
        erasingEnabled = false;
        document.removeEventListener("mouseover", eraser);
        document.addEventListener("mouseover", coloring);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mouseover", coloring);
        document.addEventListener("mouseover", eraser);
    }
});

function eraser(event){
    let elem = event.target.closest('div');
    if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function coloring(event) {
    let elem = event.target.closest('div');
    if (!elem || elem.parentNode.id != "container") return;
    let randColor1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    let randColor2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    let randColor3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randColor1}, ${randColor2}, ${randColor3})`;
}
```